# Trying to publish a shapefile on GeoServer but the OpenLayers link on Layer preview can't find layer

Tags: geoserver

I am having difficulties opening the OpenLayers link on the layer preview on GeoServer.

First I have trouble setting up a workspace on GeoServer. What is the workspace uri? I tried using one from the tutorial and from the demos present upon the installation of the server.

I then followed the various steps on the online documentation but in the end I get the download of this ugly XML file telling me the layer was not found.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver /schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> 
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   
<ServiceException code="LayerNotDefined" locator="layers">
      Could not find layer tutoWorkspace:final polygons
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Where am I possibly going wrong?

The namespace URI (which I still do not understand the criteria for its choice) or some other basic step.

I will be running the server offline.

Comment: please look in the log file and see what the error message is. The workspace URI can be any URI you like but should be different to the other workspaces. What happens if you add your shapefile to an existing workspace?

Comment: Thanks I had to download a series of videos from youtube to get myself out! Thanks for the concern

Answer (score 1):

The vector is not linked to the workspace due to an invalid workspace URI. 
The URI for an offline service adding http:// before the localhost reference does the work.